# In Swift, what is the keyword to learn about "dynamic class type"?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I remember I read somewhere about something that's more or less like this:

```
class Process <T> {
    var data: Array<T> = [];
    func addData (element: T) { data.append(T); }
}
```

This way, I can instantiate the object like this:

```
let objInt = Process <Int>
objInt.addData (100);

let objString = Process <String>
objString.addData ("Hello");
```

I want to know what is this "T", how it works, how to implement it, and how to create a class that is partially based on this dynamic type "T". But I don't know what is the keyword to search on the internet for this. I search for dynamic type in Swift, but all google returns me is about identifying and printing class' run-time dynamic type. Can somebody helps? Thanks.

Comment: It's "generics".

Comment: @zneak Alrighty! Thanks!!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean generics. Here is the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html)

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

**Generics**

From [Swift programming language book](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html)

"Generic code enables you to write flexible, reusable functions and types that can work with any type, subject to requirements that you define. You can write code that avoids duplication and expresses its intent in a clear, abstracted manner."

The generic version uses a placeholder type name (called T or any other name) instead of an actual type name (such as Int, String, or Double). So in your case Process class can hold data of any type which is specified by T parameter.